# Determine if a directory name has more than 260 characters

Tags: python

I have exported a txt file with directories and files and I'm trying to find out if the directories have 260 characters or more. I have part of my script set up with an input of the file, opening the file, and looping through the file. I am stuck at the point on what to put in the `if` statement in the loop. I think I'm supposed to use `\` as the delimiter and search within those to see if any of the text is >= 260. How to build this script?

> C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office14\Groove\ToolData\groove.net\GrooveForms4\FormsStyles\GrayCheck

```
fname = raw_input("Enter filename: ")
fhand = open(fname)
for line in fhand:
    # What here?
```

Comment: Do you mean any of the paths (e.g. `C:\Users\Bob`) is over 260 characters or any of the directories in that path (e.g. `Users`) is over 260 characters?

Comment: @Markus: Was thinking the same.

Comment: I meant any directory >= 260 characters.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>You can check the length of a string (or basically anything with length for that matter) using the built-in [`len()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#len) function:</strike>

```
fname = raw_input("Enter filename: ")
fhand = open(fname)
for line in fhand:
    if len(line) >= 260:
        # Do stuff
    else:
        # Do other stuff
```

[If you would prefer to check if the length of any directory in the path is over 260 characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32172659/determine-if-a-directory-name-has-more-than-260-characters/32172693#comment52231690_32172659), you should go with [`str.split()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split):

```
for line in fhand:
    directories = line.replace('\\', '/').split('/')
    for directory in directories:
        if len(directory) >= 260:
            # Do stuff
        else:
            # Do other stuff
```

I've also added the `str.replace('\\', '/')` for consistency: you can now add paths with either `/` or `\` as the separator.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check if one of the directory names is bigger than 260 chars you should go with [str.split](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.split). You brought the backslash into the game so thats why I am referring to this one. Then this works like this.

```
path = "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office14\Groove\ToolData\groove.net\GrooveForms4\FormsStyles\GrayCheck"
directories = path.split("\\")
for directory in directories:
    if len(directory) >= 260:
        pass # your code goes here
```

**But I think what you actually want is not the length of the directory name**, you are looking for directory paths which has a limit of characters in Windows, correct? Then there is no need to bring the backslash into the game. The simple solution is check for `len(dirname) >= 260`

```
for line in fhand:
    if len(line) >= 260:
        pass # your code goes here
```